# How to validate a user role using jaas and redirect user to specific module on the basis of Role

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, jboss, jaas

Target:
I have 5 roles defined in web.xml and I need to implement the JAAS form based auth. I am successfully able to login but authentication based redirection is not working and still I am on login page with error that says invalid username or password. I cant understand how to handle this. Also, A user can have multiple roles and the user can roam anywhere on basis of this. I am using JSF, primefaces, Wildfly 10.x, Maven build structure, Mysql as database and JAAS obviously.

I have searched over web but no solution was able to solve my problem and I am still struggling.

Here is my web.xml

```
<security-role>
<description>Administrator</description>
<role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Accounting</description>
    <role-name>ACCOUNTS</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>HR Management</description>
    <role-name>HR</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>normal pages</description>
    <role-name>BASIC</role-name>
</security-role>


<login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <realm-name>custom-authentication-security</realm-name>
     <form-login-config>
          <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>

          <form-error-page>/index.xhtml?fail=true</form-error-page>

     </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>custom-authentication-security</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
         <http-method>POST</http-method>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
         <role-name>HR</role-name>
         <role-name>ACCOUNTS</role-name>
         <role-name>BASIC</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

jboss-web.xml is

```
<jboss-web>
        <security-domain>custom-authentication-security</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Here is the security domain definded in standalone.xml:

```
 <security-domain name="custom-authentication-security" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.hotel.security.JAASLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

and finally my login() and commit() specified in JAASLoginModule :

```
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Login Mathod Called");

        if (callbackHandler == null){
            throw new LoginException("Error: no CallbackHandler available " +
            "to garner authentication information from the user");
        }
        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("username");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password: ", false);

        try {

            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            username = ((NameCallback)callbacks[0]).getName();
            password = ((PasswordCallback)callbacks[1]).getPassword();

            if (debug) {
                LOGGER.debug("Username :" + username);
                LOGGER.debug("Password : " + new String(password));
            }

            if (username == null || password == null) {
                LOGGER.error("Callback handler does not return login data properly");
                throw new LoginException("Callback handler does not return login data properly"); 
            }
            System.out.println("Username:"+username);
            System.out.println("password:"+new String(password));
            System.out.println("isValidUser:"+isValidUser());


            if (isValidUser()) { //validate user.
                succeeded = true;
                return true;
            } 

        } catch (IOException e) { 
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        if (succeeded == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Adding Principals");

            userPrincipal = new JAASUserPrincipal(username);
            if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(userPrincipal)) {
                subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);
                LOGGER.debug("User principal added:" + userPrincipal);
            }
            passwordPrincipal = new JAASPasswordPrincipal(new String(password)); 
            if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(passwordPrincipal)) {
                subject.getPrincipals().add(passwordPrincipal);
                LOGGER.debug("Password principal added: " + passwordPrincipal);
            }

            //populate subject with roles.
            List<String> roles = Arrays.asList( new String[] {"ADMIN","HR","ACCOUNT","BASIC"});
            for (String role: roles) {
                JAASRolePrincipal rolePrincipal = new JAASRolePrincipal(role);
                if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(rolePrincipal)) {
                    System.out.println("Adding role :"+ role);
                    subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal); 
                    LOGGER.debug("Role principal added: " + rolePrincipal);
                }
            }

            SessionManagerBean sessionBean=SessionFactoryImpl.getSessionManagerBean();
            sessionBean.setCurrentCuser(new CUserServiceImpl().getUserByName(username));

            sessionBean.setIsadmin(true);

            sessionBean.setIsuserloggedin(true);
            sessionBean.setUsername(username);
            sessionBean.setPassword(new String(password));

            commitSucceeded = true;

            LOGGER.info("Login subject were successfully populated with principals and roles"); 

            return true;
       }
   }
```

Now, when I am trying to access any page with url /user/ChangePassword.xhtml it redirect me to login.xhtml and when I pass incorrect credentials, is returns me to same page. that is correct. but URL is not changing to /index.xhtml this is **issue -1**.

When I pass correct login id and password, the URL changes to http://localhost:8080/HotelManager/user/j_security_check and once again I am getting message invalid userid password.

After successful login, it should be redirected to /user/ChangePassword.xhtml **issue -2**.

I need to handle a user and redirect him/her to specific page on the basis of Role **issue -3**.

Finding solution. Hope experts can help well.

Pardon me if I am not able to explain the situation properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @lukasz-stelmach can you help me.